# How to move an object while the animation is going on?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, scripting

I added a jump animation with the character in unity and to move the character I have some code like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 1 * jumpSpeed);
        Anim.SetTrigger("is_jumping");
    }
```

But here the character first moving its position (like a glitch) and then doing the animation. How can I make them happen at the same time?

Comment: See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69843/moving-a-character-according-to-the-animation-rather-than-code?rq=1

Comment: Also see https://forum.unity.com/threads/gameobject-wont-move-when-i-attach-an-animation-controller.210822/ for a more detailed explanation and multiple options to solve the problem.